# Celery @worker_process_init.connect is not running at worker startup

Tags: python-3.x, celery

I'm running Celery on Windows, which I know isn't supported in version 4, but it's still working with eventlet for the most part.

I am trying to run this init function when starting the worker:

```
db = None

@worker_process_init.connect
def init_worker(**kwargs):
    print('Initializing database connection for worker.')
    global db
    db = DB(dbname=os.getenv('DBNAME'))
```

I'm using this command to run the worker:
`celery -A celeryapp.tasks worker -l info -P eventlet -c 8 -Q database`

I'm not sure if it's a Windows thing, an eventlet thing, or something else, but my init function isn't running when starting the worker.

Answer (score 2):

`worker_process_init` is not running because there is no "worker process" that is started.

If you refer to the celery [doc](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/signals.html#worker-process-init), it says that `worker_process_init` is "dispatched in all pool **child processes** when they start". In this context, **child process means worker process**.

When you use eventlet, gevent, or any other thread based pool, they don't start child processes. In order to start child processes, you need to use multi-processing pool, such as **prefork** (default).

If you are trying to initialize a database connection when a worker starts, you might want to look into `worker_init`.